# How checksum is calculated?

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hadoop2, checksum, crc32

When I use hdfs dfs -checksum /file.txt in terminal, it gives 
/file.txt   MD5-of-0MD5-of-512CRC32C
000002000000000000000000ccfadcfdcff630efa5628fb72620d535

How it was calculated?

Upto my understanding, crc-32 used to calculate the checksum of the file.

How crc-32 calculates the checksum value?

Answer (score 0):

It´s not `CRC32` it is `CRC32C` which is used. It´s calculated parallel using 3 streams and so it´s faster than `CRC32`. Also the used polymonals are different for each process (0x1EDC6F41, reversed 0x82F63B78).
The used algorythm is still the same like `CRC32`.

If you want to see the algorythm - [have a look here on WIKI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check#CRC-32_algorithm)

Comment: A commonly used error-detecting code is CRC-32 (32-bit cyclic redundancy check), which computes a 32-bit integer checksum for input of any size. CRC-32 is used for checksumming in Hadoop’s ChecksumFileSystem, while HDFS uses a more efficient variant called CRC-32C. what is the diiference?

Comment: Calculating parallel, other polynoms - both got 32bit length and same algorythm - but other variables for polynoms - just like I told you. So you can´t use CRC-32 if they want you to use CRC32C. Thats it.